# List does not exist Error when opening the views

Tags: sharepoint-designer, document-library, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, list-template

I created a list template without including Content for a Document library and created a Library using that Template. But in the newly created library, lot of my views are showing the below error.

List does not exist. The page you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.

Correlation ID:8f938e9c-f3f8-70e4-e9c6-d4805fdfb17f

And i have full control permissions for the list. And  And i am working in SharePoint 2013 office 365.

Please let me when i am getting such error

Comment: Did you modified the Pages with sharepointdesigner before you created the template?

Comment: i made some modifications for the content type new forms.

Answer (score 3):

I had an similar Problem. Openup the sharepoint designer and go to the list. 
In the Details you will se the list guid

[image]

Take the guid and open the pages with sharepoint designer in wich the error occur. Search for "WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart". In this there exist a attribute that is named ListId. Check if it is the same id from the list.

After that you must open up the dialogs for the list e.g. (DispForm.aspx).
Search for "WebPartPages:ListFormWebPart" In this you will se s.th. like this

[image]

Check here also the list Id. In my case I had an different ID in there und got a similar error message like you.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It was showing same List Id for me in both places.

Answer (score 0):

If your imported list contain lookup column delete first all lookup column and create new look up.

Comment: try to elaborate instead of 1 liner